# How to (1) force zrange (2) the axis labels parallel in 3D plot using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to set the zrange in 3D plot from -0.04 to 0.04 as follows

```
`set zrange [-0.04:0.04]
```

this show the ztics from -0.04 to 0.04 but it leaves some space between the ztics and the x axis,
1- how to remove this space so the ztics start at intercept with x-axis
2- how to make the x and y labels parallel to their axis

[image]

Comment: Maybe `xyplane`? See for example [Remove “empty space” in splot with log scaled z axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344732/4440445)

Comment: great that's help, any suggestions for point 2?

Comment: ... did you try adding `rotate parallel` ?

Comment: when I put " set ylabel "d/dt C_{10}C_{11}C_{12}C_{13} [°/fs]" offset character 0, 0, 0 font "Helvetica-Bold,35" textcolor lt -1 rotate parallel"   it gives ';' expected at parallel